# Google Custom Search with no sites and "Search entire web" returns way less results than normal google search

Tags: google-custom-search, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to create a simple python program that returns the ratio of search results between two keywords (two searches in total, thus). However, the google-api-python-client that uses my Custom Search Engine always returns about 10x less results than a normal google search.

I don't have any restrictions in the CSE except I've set it to use 'google.fi' and set the user geolocation as Finland, because that mirrors the way I normally search on Google on the web.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list
You can adjust the number of results returned with the "num" parameter. However:

> Valid values are integers between 1 and 10, inclusive.